# swift4: dismiss current view controller and show another controller without navigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift4, xcode9

in my app i wanted to show a new view controller by dismissing current view controller. here is my attempt:

```
@IBAction func go_back_btn_pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goOrders")
        vc!.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
}
```

I tried doing this with this code but it show error. Error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'goOrders''
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eeab1e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e540031 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   UIKit                               0x00000001105f33eb -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 0
>       3   ProArt                              0x000000010d5483c0 _T06ProArt25SelectPhotoViewControllerC19go_back_btn_pressedySo8UIButtonCFyycfU_ + 192
>       4   ProArt                              0x000000010d549e3d _T06ProArt25SelectPhotoViewControllerC19go_back_btn_pressedySo8UIButtonCFyycfU_TA + 13
>       5   ProArt                              0x000000010d4efd7d _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR + 45
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010fe4fd02 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1346
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001100d3f00 -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 44
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010fe53b72 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.436 + 183
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000110a37274 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 102
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010fe4caee -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 251
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010fe4c765 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1397
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010fe4ed9c -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010fd72f09 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 343
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010fd7354c -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 293
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010fd73600 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 473
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fb277a9 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 323
>       17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000113c4f848 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000113c5a92b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee6dc99 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee31ea6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee3130b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
>       22  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001174e7a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       23  UIKit                               0x000000010fcde0b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       24  ProArt                              0x000000010d52d6f7 main + 55
>       25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113ccc955 start + 1
>   )

But in my app there is a identifier with "goOrders". Here is it

[image]

Comment: check your storyboardIdentifier once, \

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I checked it. I added an image in my question. you can see this

Comment: You named your segue goOrders, but not the controller identifier.

Comment: 1. View controller with "goOrders" as identifier should be present in storyboard.   2. It should be self.present.. not vc!.present.

Answer (score 1):

1-You have to set **goOrders** id here

**connection less**

[image]

2- Don't use a new VC to present itself

**connection oriented**

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
     let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goOrders")

     // if it will be the root
         UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

//

or present it in viewDidAppear of the presentingVC

Comment: I have done it. But still shows error. 
error: 
2018-04-23 13:28:36.951524+0600 ProArt[2812:119823] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <ProArt.OrdersViewController: 0x7fa3b75694c0>.'

Comment: you can't say VC.present(VC ,,,,,,,,, as VC is not yet presented and can't present itself , you have to use self.present(VC ,,,, inside viewDidAppear of the VC that will Appear after you dismiss the current or set it to window root if that's your flow logic

Comment: added storyboard id as "goOrders" and uses both of those code. 

// self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goOrders")
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }) // and 

// self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goOrders", sender: self)
        }) //

But it does not work

Comment: Do you use navigationController ??

Comment: No, I have not use navigationController